# How to create an accordion in Xamarin.Forms ListView

Tags: c#, listview, accordion, xamarin.forms

How can I create an accordion in a `ListView` with data binding?
I am creating this app with `Xamarin.Forms`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<ListView x:Name="List" HasUnevenRows="True" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Text="ABC:-" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row ="0"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding ABC}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Label Text="XYZ:-" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row ="1"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding XYZ}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
           </Grid>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: Have you already fixed this issue? If not, what elements are you wanting to expand and collapse? Do you want each `ViewCell` to be able to expand and collapse or each `Grid` within a `ViewCell` or each `Label` within the `Grid`?

Comment: @hvaughan3 each grid within a viewcell

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the thread below which lists a few options for this. Our accordion view was not within a `ListView` but we basically just used `WidthRequest` and a little animation to make various `WebView`s expand and collapse.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33975/how-to-implement-expandable-collapsible-listview-in-xamarin-forms